# Volume integral boundaries

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I find the integration boundaries for the volume integral of 
$$M:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+cy^2-f(z)^2\le 0\}$$
$f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+_0$, $c> 0$.

Comment: I think you may have an infinite surface there. For example, with $\;c=1\;,\;\;f(z)=z\;$ , we get $$\;x^2+y^2-z^2\le0\iff z^2\ge x^2+y^2$$ and this is all the space *above and below* the double cone$\; z^2=x^2+y^2\;$ , which has no fixed, finite boundaries...Perhaps some info is lacking?

Comment: That's all the information I got. Is the surface not bounded due to $z\in[a,b]$?

Comment: @V Yes, I missed that piece of info...but we must then assume $\;f\;$ is continuous. Let me check now...

Comment: @DonAntonio Does something like $f(a)^2\le f(z)^2\le f(b)^2$, $-f(z)\le cy^2\le f(z)$ and $-\sqrt{f(z)^2-cy^2}\le x\le\sqrt{f(z)^2-cy^2}$ maybe look ok?

Comment: $-f(z)\le \sqrt{c}y\le f(z)$ of course